# Vertical centering text with image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have one problem, i wan't to add image and vertical center align image. This looks like this
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzA1z.png)

I wan't to look like this:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qcsO.png)

My code:

```
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  p {
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<img src="./image.jpg" class="img"> <p>Test</p>
```

I tried this, but is there some better way to fix this problem?

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -1.76em;
  }
```

Comment: Look into flexbox. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

In your .img class add a `vertical-align:middle;` and it should do the trick.

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }

  p {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<img src="./image.jpg" class="img"> <p>Test</p>
```

Comment: Why does this work? The img, the p(inline block) ..?